# How does a var inside While Loop intercept Print function and manipulate outside var?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm new to Python but having a hard time to understand the following While Loop code as it behaves very differently. I know this code work but I do not know HOW IT WORK. Top Python experts also have no idea.

```python
x = 1
while x < 10:
    print x
    x = x + 1 ## How does this VAR manipulate Print as the VAR comes late in the code?
```

I do not know whether this related to control flow or global var. Please help me out to understand deeper.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. What are you confused about? I think this is a question of declaration and I initialization vs reassignment.

Comment: Is this a question about scope?

Comment: You're increasing the value of `x` by 1 in each iteration of the loop. When `x=10` you'll break out of the loop. When you exit the loop: `x=10`.

Comment: There is only 1 variable named `x` in your script.

Comment: Each occurence of `x` is in same scope (local scope) in your code. So incrementing `x` will reflect *right* after the end of while loop. You should refer to variable scopes documentation in Python.

Comment: I follow **LEGB** rule for scope resolution. You can Google about this.

Comment: `Top Python experts also have no idea.` This seems highly unlikely! Beware of learning from people who don't really know what they are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your question is about scope. In the above example, a new memory address for `var x` is created on the first line and any code on lines 2,3,4 that access `x` can read/write to that variable.

There are only two rules here that we need to follow:

1. `x` must be declared before `print` so that print can access that piece of memory
2. `print` must be in the same or inner scope to access 'x'

Example 1 - valid (because we follow rules 1 and 2)

```
x = 1
print x
```

Example 2 - valid (because we follow rules 1 and 2)

```
x = 1
while x < 10:
    print x
    x = x + 1
```

Example 3 - valid (because we follow rules 1 and 2)

```
x = 1
while x < 10:
    print x
    x = x + 1
print x
```

Example 4 - NOT valid (because we don't follow rule 1 and `print` is accessing a variable that has not yet been created in memory)

```
print x    
x = 1
```

Example 5 - NOT valid (because we don't follow rule 2 and `print` doesn't have access to our variable's scope, `x` no longer exists in memory)

```
y = 1
while y < 5:
    x = 1
    y = y + 1
print x
```

It would do you good to read this entire section on [variable lifetime and scope in python](https://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html#variables) all the way through **Exercise 1** for good practice.

Comment: What bout this one? x = 1
while x < 10:
    x = x + 1
    print x

Comment: The results start from 2 to 9 in other code I mentioned in the above comment while the main question code results start from 1 to 9.

Comment: I actually understand that basic example 1 but when it comes to while loop related binding things getting messy for me.

Comment: i can't understand your example because in python tabbing is important

Comment: this isn't even valid syntax, you need to review the basic docs on python indentation

Comment: I'm sorry for not putting tabs. https://pastebin.com/qtqM5dt1 and this code work. It prints from 2 to 9.

Comment: There is nothing like an 'inner scope' in Python, and indented blocks **don't** create a new scope. Your example 5 works perfectly. For more information about scoping rules, see for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/292502/550094

Answer (score 0):

`x = 1 #Declares the variable
while x < 10: #checks whether the value of x is less than 10 every time the loop runs
    print x #prints value of x for the each iterations(1 for first iteration, 2 for second and so on)
    x = x + 1 #this is the update part`
 Let me tell you one more thing, you do not have any case of global variable here. 
 If you have trouble in understanding whether its global or local declaration, I would recommend you to follow this [link](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/global-local-nonlocal-variables)

Answer (score -1):

Counter variable act like a tiny persistent storage. While loop checks whether the stored value in that tiny persistent storage **Less** than 11. If the value less than 10 then it starts the loop. Inside the loop, it instructs to Print value 1 because it's the current value in that tiny persistent storage after that the other "x" inside loop instruct that tiny persistent storage to update value by adding +1. This loop continues until it gets alert from persistent storage that value stored in persistent storage met 10 value.  The loop will successfully exist.

This little software helped me to understand behind scenes http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html

Conclusion:

It seems **For loops** better for this kind things because it's clean and easy to maintain but understanding this concept is also important

Comment: This answer to your own question is ridden with errors and misunderstandings. There is no comparison to 11, only to 10. There is no 'other' x variable, as all of your code is part of the same scope. There is no such thing as an 'alert from persistent storage to the loop'.  This shouldn't be the accepted answer.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I'm sorry but I made it easier for a newbie to understand. You are correct about 10. I put 11 by mistake. "alert from persistent storage to the loop" means the code check current memory.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille What kind of definition you have for other "x' inside the code if it, not a variable?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille Are you there?